# Do ClickOnce Deployments work with SharePoint Online (AD FS)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, adfs

I've built a windows forms application (clickonce) and deployed to SharePoint Online.  I then click on the associated .application file and I get a 403 error.  Here's what I see in the clickonce log file:

> Activation of "URL to application file" resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>
> - Downloading "URL to application file" did not succeed.
> - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Has anyone had success with ClickOnce apps deploying on SharePoint Online configured with AD FS?  If so, do you have any idea of what my issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question - but I would I venture a guess that not all the files were uploaded to the same location.  The setup.exe file just installs pre-reqs and makes a call to the .application file for installation.

see similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082410/clickonce-setup-exe-fails-but-the-application-file-works-fine-when-using-a-win